# Matrix Similar to an Upper Triangular with ones along the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $k$ is an algebraically closed field $V$ is $n$-dimensional $k$-vector space and $A \in M_n(k)$ is a $k$-endomorphism of $V$. Then it is true that $A$ is similar to an upper-triangular matrix $U$ i.e. there is an ordered $k$-basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$ such that $P^{-1}[A]_{\mathcal{B}}P=U$. Is it true though, that we can choose the matrix $U$ to have "ones" along its diagonal?

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & * & ... & * \\
    0 & 1 & ... & * \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & ... & 1
  \end{bmatrix}

Also given a finite family of $k$-endomorphisms of V, can we choose such a basis where all the endomorphisms with respect to that basis have the above form simultaneously?

Comment: The eigenvalues of $U$ are on its diagonal. Similarities preserve eigenvalues, so you're not free to choose the diagonal of $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over an algebraically closed field, it is indeed true that every matrix can be triangularized. A more general condition would be that a matrix is triangularizable if and only if its minimal polynomial splits over the base field.

Now, the eigenvalues of any triangular matrix is precisely displayed on its diagonal. You are free to choose the ordering of these eigenvalues, but you may not *change* the eigenvalues themselves. So you are not free to make the diagonals of $U$ all $1$. The diagonal elements have to be the eigenvalues of $A$.

For your second question, you may know that a family of diagonalizable matrices is simultaneously diagonalizable if and only if they are a commuting family. This carries over (in part) to triangularizable matrices as well. A family of triangularizable matrices is simultaneously triangularizable if they are mutually commuting. So matrices commuting is a sufficient condition for simultaneous triangularization, but unlike the diagonalizable case, it is not longer necessary. I'm not aware of a useful necessary condition for the triangularizable case.